# The accuracy of the training set and test set suddenly drops, the loss suddenly rises, but slowly recovers

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the process of training the LSTM model, I originally fixed the learning rate of 0.0001, but periodically experienced a loss increase and a decrease in accuracy during the training process, as in the following figure.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJQgx.png)

I think there is a bad sample, but I have this problem on multiple libraries. I consider using the learning rate decay and modifying the beta value of the Adam optimizer. Although the shock is solved, it will be greatly reduced performance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJa3C.png)

So I would like to ask the following questions:
1. Why can I fix this problem by modifying beta, but it leads to a decrease in accuracy?
2. If it is a bad sample, why do you have this problem in multiple databases? (ps: I used the same way to extract features, maybe because of this?) Will it be the reason for the model?
3. What should I do if I want to delete bad samples?

Comment: You should probably post your question on more data-science related SE websites like [crossvalidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [datascience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 points: 1. check your parameter setting of BN, if you have used BN. 
2. - https://discuss.gluon.ai/t/topic/3386

Comment: Thanks, it may useful